# Visual Studio ASP.NET Core MVC web app doesnt open browser after i run it

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I try and run the program it says that the build is ready and after a bit, it says this in the console

> Failed to download package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.5.0.17' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.language/5.0.17/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.language.5.0.17.nupkg'.
>
> Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'SslStream'.
>
> Failed to download package 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.3.8.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp/3.8.0/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.3.8.0.nupkg'.
>
> The HTTP request to 'GET [https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp/3.8.0/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.3.8.0.nupkg'](https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp/3.8.0/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.3.8.0.nupkg%27) has timed out after 100000ms.

Comment: Rebuild your Project and try it again. It seems some packages has not downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and run the code "npm start" then app will be start on your browser.